# Filtering compound columns in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have these two tables in a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP96GwK2_rBGYjMYnp37OWIRqTHPSxIrqlL-8eiLRyY/edit?usp=sharing):

Given `Table A` and `Table B` I want to output `Table C` (values from Table A + `You` row with value for each date).

[image]

Is there any easy way to do so (I plan to use apps script as well)?

I have tried to filter two columns with this `custom formula` but it didn't work:

`=QUERY(A:B; "where A='2021-01-25' and B='You|domain1'"; 0)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your idea right and how long will be the dataset.
So I tried to build an universal formula.

I assume that you have an indicator in your table that gives you idea who the winner is.
I took 'value' from each day as this indicator.

First we need to find winners for each day:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(E10:E12, sort($A$10:$C$19,1,1,3,0),{1,2,3},true))
```

This gives me:

2021-01-25  domain1 1.00%

2021-01-26  domain2 6.00%

2021-01-27  domain1 8.00%

Then I take source table and filter entries with "You"

```
=filter(A10:C19,B10:B19="You")
```

This gives me:

2021-01-25  You 5.00%

2021-01-26  You 7.00%

2021-01-27  You 10.00%

Final step is to combine these tables together and sort by date.

```
=sort({ArrayFormula(vlookup(E10:E12, sort($A$10:$C$19,1,1,3,0),{1,2,3},true));filter(A10:C19,B10:B19="You")},1,1)
```

My result looks like this:

2021-01-25  domain1 1.00%

2021-01-25  You 5.00%

2021-01-26  domain2 6.00%

2021-01-26  You 7.00%

2021-01-27  domain1 8.00%

2021-01-27  You 10.00%

My solution is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOPTmH8S9ir27wlk7BrXZJ3uthgC0xqwqMYiSf_MkqE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, is it even syntactically correct to fill the custom formula that way? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t1KJ.png